# Is it possible to make the jQuery DateTimePicker not default to the current date and time upon giving it an invalid value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, time

For example, if I input 99 for month or 77 for day, or 66 for hour or 76 for minutes, it automatically defaults to the current date and time. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Unlikely. For what reason would you ever want that behaviour?

Comment: There is already a validation in place that deals with this, and the user might get confused upon seeing the current date and time upon entering a wrong value or they might not even notice it and get a wrong query result as a result of this. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I think you may be over-analysing this. I've used several date controls with this behaviour and had no reports of any of them 'confusing users' with an incorrect date. You'd have to be massively confused to enter '99' in a date field anyway, and then if the value changed to a date that would surely make the purpose of the field *clearer*, not more confusing. Depending on the control you're using there may be an 'error' event you could handle and notify the user of their mistake. Check the docs.